# First letter alone in Upper Case Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying out to make the first letter alone in Upper case.

```
select 
     case
          when 'G' then 'GERMANY'
          when 'US' then 'AMERICA'
          when 'S' then 'SPAIN
          else 'unknown'
from 
     customer
```

Oracle output:
GERMANY
AMERICA
 SPAIN

my not working 'solution'

```
select 
     case initcap(land)
          when 'G' then 'GERMANY'
          when 'US' then 'AMERICA'
          when 'S' then 'SPAIN
          else 'unknown'
from 
     customer
```

Oracle output:
GERMANY
AMERICA
 SPAIN

Comment: Hint: `UPPER`, `LOWER`, and `SUBSTR`

Comment: How does your SQL code relate to the question? I am sure you can write `...when 'G' then 'Germany'...`

Comment: No idea what you mean... what is your expected result, and why isn't that what you get from initcap? What is the `land` value - is that the G/US/S you're using for the case expression? If so why not just have your result string literals in the case you want; and what should happen to `unknown`?

Comment: Can you try to explain why you don't need `Initcap`?

Comment: @trincot, you mean you are _not_ sure ;-)

Comment: I have to change the code. Of couse I can replace GERMANY to germany but I have to add a function that does this work for me. I found initcap but dont know how to use it in this situation.

Comment: But as you seem to write a case `when` clause for each abbreviation already, why do you consider writing `Germany` more work than writing `GERMANY`?

Comment: Its a school exercise dont ask me :D I only have to change the letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since everyone has to make assumptions about what you need, here is my attempt at understanding what you are looking for -

```
SELECT INITCAP (
          CASE land
             WHEN 'G' THEN 'GERMANY'
             WHEN 'US' THEN 'AMERICA'
             WHEN 'S' THEN 'SPAIN'
             ELSE 'unknown'
          END)
  FROM customer;
```

I would however argue that unless you have some sort of way to auto-generate these case statements (which I doubt), why not just write `WHEN 'G' THEN 'Germany'` in the first place.

Comment: thats it thanks! Is there another way to get the same solution? maybe something with substr?

Comment: Nice! Haven't worked in Oracle in a while. Didn't think to `INITCAP` the whole `CASE`. +1

Comment: Depends on whether for 'UK' you want 'United kingdom' or 'United Kingdom'. If it is the former, see MT0's answer for using SUBSTR.

Comment: Ok I replaced initcap with SELECT UPPER( SUBSTR( land, 1, 1 ) ) || LOWER( SUBSTR( land, 2 ) )
 but it doesnt work

Comment: @HansBaum - that's the same mistake you made before. You need the case expression inside the `substr()`, not the short land value. Which means you either need to repeat the whole case expression in each `substr()`, or use an inline view or CTE. As MTO's edited answer shows.

Answer (score 4):

Take the first character sub-string and apply `UPPER()` to it and then take the remaining sub-string and apply `LOWER()` to it:

```
SELECT UPPER( SUBSTR( land, 1, 1 ) ) || LOWER( SUBSTR( land, 2 ) )
FROM   customer
```

Applying this to your query - you can just nest one select inside another:

```
SELECT UPPER( SUBSTR( land, 1, 1 ) ) || LOWER( SUBSTR( land, 2 ) )
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE land
              WHEN 'G'  THEN 'GERMANY'
              WHEN 'US' THEN 'AMERICA'
              WHEN 'UK' THEN 'UNITED KINGDOM'
              WHEN 'S'  THEN 'SPAIN
                        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
         END AS land
  FROM   customer
)
```

Comment: @AlexPoole I assumed that they were considering `united kingdom` and wanted it formatted as `United kingdom` - since the OP said that they had tried `INITCAP()` and their unclear comments make it seem like it was not working for them. If they do want to capitalise the first letter of each word then they can of-course just use `INITCAP()` as they've suggested in their post (but why post the question then?).

Comment: @HansBaum See my update on a simple method of how to apply it to your query.

Answer (score 2):

OK, you're calling `initcap()` at the wrong point; you need the **result** of the case expression inside the call:

```
select initcap(case land
  when 'G' then 'GERMANY'
  when 'US' then 'AMERICA'
  when 'S' then 'SPAIN'
  else 'unknown'
  end)
from customer
```

At the moment you're changing 'G' to 'G', which does nothing; that would only be useful if you had land set to 'g'.

Demo:

```
with customer (land) as (
  select 'S' from dual
  union all select 'G' from dual
  union all select 'US' from dual
  union all select 'UK' from dual
)
select initcap(case land
  when 'G' then 'GERMANY'
  when 'US' then 'AMERICA'
  when 'S' then 'SPAIN'
  else 'unknown'
  end)
from customer;

INITCAP
-------
Spain  
Germany
America
Unknown
```

It would of course, as has been commented already, be much simpler to have `when 'G' then 'Germany'` etc.; and in the real world the country names would probably be in a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna take a stab at what you mean. Your tag says Oracle, so INITCAP(str) is definitely what you need if you're doing it on a `SELECT`, but you can just type the strings as you want them if the code provided is what you're doing.

```
select case
when 'G' then 'Germany'
when 'US' then 'America'
when 'S' then 'Spain'
else 'Unknown'
from customer
```

May be worth noting you were missing a single quote after "Spain".

## EDIT RESPONSE:

You need to call `INITCAP()` on the output not the input.

```
select case
when 'G' then INITCAP('GERMANY')
when 'US' then INITCAP('AMERICA')
when 'S' then INITCAP('SPAIN')
else INITCAP('unknown')
from customer
```

Comment: I know this works but I have to add a function that does the work for me

Comment: @HansBaum - you have to *create* a function, or you have to *call* a built-in function?

Comment: @HansBaum can you edit your post? We need you to show exactly what you tried, and exactly what you want to see. How did you use INITCAP()? This is almost certainly the function you need.